# How to fit kegging into a small house

Tags: kegging, corny-keg, kegerator

We have a very tiny house. I brew in the garage and bottle there. I want to keg so bad but I am having trouble finding room for some kegs (in something to keep them cold). Anyone have some genius idea to store a kegging system in my house that would hold at least 2 kegs, if not 3+.

More details: single story on a crawl, anything outdoors will freeze, I have an attic and I'm not afraid to use it or the crawl, but I don't know what is possible.

Comment: What's your room temp and what's the way you want to use your keg system (frequence, time to empty one keg, alone or with more people, etc)?

Comment: Our house is about 67F, I assume there is a good amount of variance up and down from there.

Between me and my wife and my guests each weekend we probably drink ~20 beers/week. So 2-3 weeks per corny? ...depending on how many we had and what was popular. If we had 2 cornys it would be ~4-6 weeks to empty them, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1: Kegerator. Can be [bought](http://www.kegerator.com/) or [built](http://www.brewreviewcrew.com/how-to-build-kegerator/) (google for DIY Kegerators and you will see many more options). Building gives you the option to find a fridge that fits into a random corner and holds the amount of kegs you require. Chest freezers ([keezer](http://billybrew.com/how-to-build-a-keezer)) make great kegerators and they can still be a table.

Option 2: Store the kegs in the attic, run pipes to your taps. Use a [cold plate](http://www.thebeerkeg.co.za/catalog/dispensing-home-brew-kegging/beer-dispensing-cold-plate-single-tap.html) or [jockey box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jockey_box) to chill the beer.

Option 3: Same as option 2, but use an electric chiller. Those tend to be quite expensive.

Remember that your kegs should be stored upright and that you have to have your CO2 closeby. (There are exceptions to both).

I would first find out if I have place for a fridge/kegerator/keezer or if you have to store the kegs (and CO2) in some other location. Ask the wife is she agrees :) Now decide if the location is good for serving beer. If not, work out how to get the beer to a (again, wife approved) beer dispensing location. Decide if the beer will be chilled in keg storage location or beer dispensing location.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to carve out some space in the living room for a simple two tap towered mini fridge.  Professionally made ones can be quite attractive and will normally hold two kegs and the CO2 tank.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your setup is, but depending on your setup and if you were desperate and handy you *could* store a beer fridge/freezer in some sort of non-living area and, assuming it's close where you want to drink, run tubing and shanks through the walls.  I saw something similar years ago on a brewing forum where the guy put a beer freezer in a utility room off his finished basement bar and ran lines through the wall.

Answer (score 1):

There are small home kegerators on the market.
For example, this home kegerator can be installed even in a tight corner of your house https://www.beveragecraft.com/home-kegerator-full-size-includes-1-tap-tower/ And what I like about it you can move it around on casters.